# Passing GET Parameter to POST In Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using jQuery AJAX To pass some map coordinates to a controller with POST.
Now I'm wondering.

If the current page is

```
site.com/project/2
```

What would be a good way to pass the **2** also with POST.

#### Things I have thought of

- Adding the GET request to a hidden field?

  ```
  <input type="hidden" id="trip" value="{{ $trip->id }}" />
  ```
- Trying to get the current GET parameter with jQuery or javascript?

This is the code of my POST with Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "markers/add",
        data: {"lat": lat, "lng": lng},
        success: function(success) {
            if(success) marker.setMap(null);
        }
    });
```

And In my PHP I should have the trip_id also

```
    $marker->lat = Input::get('lat');
    $marker->lng = Input::get('lng');
    $marker->trip_id = Input::get('trip');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why would including a hidden field with the ID be bad practice? It's well within reason to pass information from the server that way so it's accesible to client side scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did indeed solve it this way. Was just curious about other possible ways ( and i've been up for a long time )

Comment: If you are passing a POST with AJAX then why is Laravel calling `Input::get()`??

Comment: Because I need to catch the post variables in Laravel? That's how the requests work in Laravel.

Comment: Well, Laravel has rustled my jimmies lol

Comment: Haha ^^ It might seem confusing indeed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `Input::get` works for `get` or `post`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking the approach of adding it as a hidden form input.  As far as I know there's no 'best practice' guideline that discourages this, and prevents you from having to write/maintain extra javascript just to add that value to the POST data.

`<pedantic>`
Strictly speaking though, that's not a GET parameter.  If it were, the URL would look more like this:

```
site.com/project?project=2
```

As it is, it's just another segment of the URL.`</pedantic>`